# Can a non-mod override a majority decision on an edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I have made [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15187091) to a post which has been voted to accept by two users, but rejected by its owner.

When two other users voted to accept, why was this rejected? The user is not a moderator and I certainly don't recall having that sort of veto myself.

Can anyone tell me what happened here? Is this normal? The grammar in the post is wrong by objective standards.

Comment: were the trivial grammar changes which really dont make any difference worth it?

Comment: They improved readability, in my view. And the majority decision agreed.

Comment: not a majority just 2 other grammar police

Comment: @nogad I am interested in readability, the inverse of which can make things unnecessarily difficult for people attempting to learn coding. Stackoverflow has massive Google presence. That comes with numerous responsibilities. Or should do. Most people agreed the edit did indeed improve readability.

Comment: Yup.  Only two kind of users have super-powers here, moderators and no-rep question askers.  This is fairly minor, and in fact this user would trivially roll the edit back, their power to destroy posts created by other users is a lot more iffy.  They got this power by complaining a lot, SE doesn't want to deal with it.  SE needs to stop pretending they can support Q+A, meta does.

Comment: The edit adds value, however little. But there's a case to be made against non-essential edits on three-year-old posts.

Comment: What's the case? Improving readability is a good thing. What's the argument against?

Comment: The fact that edits bump a question into the active status. For such a trivial edit... Some people find it's not worth kicking it back up the active page.

Comment: The post was on the list of the first posts when you search for Ruby on Rails. It was hardly hidden.

Comment: @JustIn dude... You ask why it's bad. I tell you why some people think it's bad. Arguing against it with me won't change their minds ;). And hardly hidden isn't the same as sending back up to the page of newly asked/active questions.

Comment: So you're saying it's bad because some people think it is? You can't back it up with logic. I'm saying when the majority upholds a truth it should be upheld. Not sure what you're saying tbh.

Comment: Why are you all discussing whenever the edit was valid or not? Improving the post is always welcomed. It's said in the help center.

Answer (score 9):

Authors can unilaterally reject/approve any edit on their post.

Comment: Oh. I've not been able to do that. Is that a privilege only some people get?

Comment: @JustInTimeBerlake no. As author you can always edit your post, likewise you can accept or reject any suggested edit.

Comment: Fair enough. I can edit posts after, but I've never had the option to reject an edit on my post. I personally think if an edit improves readability it should be accepted. I know there may be additional complexities. I'm not knocking the system just asking questions.

Comment: @JustInTimeBerlake you always had the option, the fact that you never get to use it is another matter altogether. If the community can get the edit sorted out before you do, there's no reason to nag at you to take a decision.

Comment: I have never had the option to reject an edit on my own post. They happen. I react. I have never had an option to react before the event. Perhaps a bug?

Comment: @JustInTimeBerlake no. Just timing. There should be a suggested edit notification right now.

Comment: I see it now...

Comment: @JustInTimeBerlake Just to add, if the edit is done by someone over 2k, it is applied immediately, so it may be a reason why you didn't had the option to reject. You always have a notification anyway when something happen to one of your post.